# Should one add bower.json in the ignore files list?

Tags: bower

Bower descriptor file (bower.json) has an 'ignore' parameter accepting pattern of files that should be removed from the installed package. Is it considered a good practice to remove bower.json file in it?

I feel like if I retrieve a package using bower, I should have access to this file because of the 'main' parameter. Bower is here to retrieve package, not to build them. But it provides the 'main' parameter to point the main resources of those package. This become useless if bower.json is removed from the installed package.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you shouldn't ignore bower.json, but even if you did Bower would just include it anyway as it's needed.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply
but I did not understand/agree with it:
1) What shouldn't I do? ignore bower.json or rely on it?
2) if you `bower install fastclick#0.6.9`, there won't be a bower.json file.

Comment: Rely on it. Though not all packages have a bower.json.

Comment: Ok, bower.json exists as '.bower.json' since bower 1.0.0 in any case.

Comment: Ok, make sense. I think I should be able to rely on '.bower.json' when using bower as I can rely on package.json when using npm. But agree it is open to further discussion.

Comment: In the [bower.json spec](https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec#ignore) it is stated that bower.json will never be ignored anyway